# What is the prayer uttered by Michael Ginberg's dad in Mad Men?

Tags: blessing, hebrew, marriage, children-parenting, popular-culture

In the [second last scene of episode 5x03 of Mad Men](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=vd-NaUEpeBw#t=32), Michael Ginsberg (one of the Jewish characters on the show) comes back home from the grocer's to be greeted by his dad. The latter encourages Michael to

> get girls; an old one and a young one.

and ends up uttering/singing what appears to be a prayer/chant while facing Michael and cupping the latter's head.

[image: Still image from the show referenced above, as described above.]

I can't understand that bit, because I know no Hebrew. What is Michael's dad saying at that moment? Is it related to his son being single or not enjoying life enough?

Comment: Poor Ginsberg - I hope he turns out OK in the next season...

Comment: @Gary I'm afraid the **pple incident was his swan song.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He is reciting [Numbers 6:24](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0406.htm#24)-26 (he only gets through half of the last verse in that clip):

> The LORD bless thee, and keep thee;
>
> The LORD make His face to shine upon thee, and be gracious unto thee;
>
> The LORD lift up His countenance upon thee, and give thee peace.

This is known as the [Priestly Blessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing) and it is sometimes used when [parents bless their children.](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/practices/Ritual/Shabbat_The_Sabbath/At_Home/Friday_Night/Blessing_the_Children.shtml)

Comment: The placing of the hands is a custom which originates from Jacob's blessing to Joseph's children Ephraim and Menashe prior to Jacob's death.